# 1049, "Unknown database 'database' " django mysql can't connect

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-ec2, database-connection

```
Exception Type: OperationalError at /
Exception Value: (1049, "Unknown database 'database'")
```

At the moment i tried this:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'database',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '****',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '/var/lib/mysql/database/',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '80',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

If i don't specify a host i get this error:

```
OperationalError at /

(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/database' (13)")
```

Can it be something with permissions?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you create the db "database" in mysql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, create the database on mysql.
Second, edit your default conection like this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'MY_DATABASE_NAME',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'MY_PASSWORD',
    }
}
```

finally run your syncdb.

> ./manage.py syncdb

Answer (score 6):

`PORT` is not the web server port, but the database port, which is `3306` for MySQL, and `HOST` is the database sever's IP or name. You probably want `127.0.0.1`.

You should create the database beforehand with `create database mydatabase charset utf8;` from the mysql prompt.

Comment: I am not local i am on a server... so i should use the same ip as the server?

Answer (score 1):

Login to mysql on Terminal and create a DB

```
mysql -u root -p

CREATE DATABASE dbname;

USE dbname;
```

Then on setting.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'root', #Mysql username
        'PASSWORD': 'password', #mysql password
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. What makes you think that the database did not exist in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can create a database by the name database. So please check the following first...

1) Have installed mysql-server and created the database with proper grant all permissions? If you have done so then check next steps

2)I dont know about Amazon, but this error was common in older versions of Linux distros from Redhat and Fedora. An option is to do this
by setting the SELINUX line in /etc/sysconfig/selinux to Disabled:

SELINUX=Disabled

Comment: mysql> create database database;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database' at line 1

Comment: no mate... i just changed it to database for stack... in real its something else